# Trouble splitting a string to an array

Tags: java, string, split

I am having trouble finding this exact question online so I thought to ask. Let's say I have a string `"0123"`. I want to split this string to an array `['0','1','2','3']`.

I know in (for example) Python you can easily do `"0123".split()` without any input, but in Java the method requires an input and even if I put empty string such as `.split("")` it doesn't work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `toCharArray();` - for example:

```
char c[]= "0123".toCharArray();
```

this is exactly same to

```
char c[]={'0','1','2','3'} ;
```

Comment: What does this return? A String[]?

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `.split()` and use a regular expression to catch every digit or character like:

```
string.split("\\d");
```

Comment: Regex argument in `split` describes in which place we want to split, not what we want to return, so `"0123".split("\\d")` would return empty array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex with the [`String.split(String regex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method:

```
String[] characters = "0123".split("|");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it as a `char[]` by using [`String.toCharArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) -

```
char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
```

Or, you could get is as a `String[]` by using [`String.split(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) like,

```
String str = "0123";
char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(chars));
String[] strings = str.split("");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strings));
```

Output is

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```